# показать форму в модальном окне Bootstrap 4

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap4

Открытие формы в модальном окне.
Страница на которой вызываем окно:

```
<a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
  Добавить
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

И сама страница формы:

```
@model CrmEnergo.Models.ContractorPersonal
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Создать</h4>
    <small class="font-bold">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</small>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Post" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Post" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Post" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
</div>
```

Все это прекрасно работало и работает в Bootstrap 3.7 но в Bootstrap 4 открывается только пустое окно, загрузка самой формы не происходит. Кто то решал уже эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на английском.

В версии 4 убрали загрузку по умолчанию. Теперь нужно обрабатывать отдельно в скрипте.

```
<script>
    $('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.modal-content').load(e.relatedTarget.href);
    });
</script>
```